# angularjs stop incrementing on uncheck of checkbox

Tags: angularjs

I have a checkbox that adds +2 if the user checks it. I need it to only do this one time. Right now the user can constantly add plus 2 which is not what I need. I need it to add it only once. (factors.Delivery is the ng-model)

I also need it to remove the --2 and stop if the checkmark is removed, but right now, it keeps subtracting.

Any help would be appreciated
Even disabling the check after clicking would be good, but it wont disable after clicking only before.

```
$scope.factors.Delivery = 0;
$scope.increment = function() {
    if ($scope.factors.Delivery >= 0) { 
         $scope.factors.Delivery+=2;
    } else {
        $scope.factors.Delivery-=2;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 is greater than or equal to 0. It sounds like the only acceptable values are 2 and 0 based on your post. I would suggest:

```
$scope.factors.Delivery = 0; 
$scope.increment = function() {
    if ($scope.factors.Delivery == 0) { 
       $scope.factors.Delivery=2;
   } else {
        $scope.factors.Delivery=0;
   }
};`
```

or using your code, you can disable the checkbox with something like this:

`ng-disabled="clickedOnce"` on the checkbox and the modifications below.

```
$scope.factors.Delivery = 0;
$scope.clickedOnce = false;
$scope.increment = function() {
    $scope.clickedOnce = true;
    if ($scope.factors.Delivery >= 0) { 
         $scope.factors.Delivery+=2;
    } else {
        $scope.factors.Delivery-=2;
    }
};
```

Comment: This needs to increment the value of an input box. The box will already have a number in it, so when its ticked, it needs to add 2 and if unticked- remove the 2 that was added

Comment: I'd think you will need to write the initial value to a cookie or session storage then and only allow a change when the value is equal to the original value. Otherwise this would be easily circumvented by clicking refresh after a change.

Comment: the numbers will not remain the same. Can you explain how do i just disable the checkbox after clicking